# Adding and removing elements from lazy initialized collection, using Hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, caching, jpa

Two entities - parent and child, in a one-to-many relationship. Significant parts:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Parent {   
    private Collection<Child> children;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public Collection<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;    
    }
}

@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Child {        
    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

I have two problems in scenarios where a child is being added or removed. The child entity is being handled (saved or deleted via Session or EntityManager), but the questions arise when trying to update the Parent entity whose child is added/deleted:

1. If the `children` collection is not initialized, on adding a child to the collection (if it is a Set instead of a Collection here in code), or on removal (any type of collection) - the collection will be initialized, which, if the collection is not cached, will result in a database query.

   To prevent this, I think some idea would be to first check conditions: if the collection is initialized (both JPA and Hibernate provide methods to check this) OR if the collection is in the cache (using a role is required to check this, which possibly has to be hardcoded) - then do the add/removal. If these conditions are not satisfied, there is no need to update the collection, as it will be up-to-date the first time it is fetched from the db.

   Is there some better way to do this, as the "solution" requires to check cache, and also to do this by using a role string (if fully qualified domain name is being used as the role, the string can be constructed by reflection, but that looks dirty and can cause a problem if tomorrow the role is given as a specific string)?
2. If the `children` collection is cached, add/removal to it will cause the collection to be invalidated in the cache, so the next time it is requested, it will be read from the db. I know collections are never updated in the cache, but what is the best way to have refreshed data in the cache right away (as at the moment of add/remove we have all the info), and not have to wait for db querying later when the collection is requested?

So the goal of these questions is to determine a *proper* way to work with (lazy initialized) collections in the described scenarios.